# androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecVideoRenderer error

Tags: android, exoplayer, playback, exoplayer2.x

Video codec error

```
androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer$DecoderInitializationException: 
 Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, Format(2, null, null, video/avc, avc1.640033, -1, null, [540, 960, 13.037374], [-1, -1])
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1015)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:539)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1447)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:920)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:948)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:763)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1015)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:510)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
                                                                                              Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.avc.dec, error 0xfffffff4 (NO_MEMORY)
                                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1999)
                                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1977)
                                                                                                  at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1947)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter$Factory.createAdapter(AsynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:95)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.createAdapter(DefaultMediaCodecAdapterFactory.java:113)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.initCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1093)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecWithFallback(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1004)
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.maybeInitCodecOrBypass(MediaCodecRenderer.java:539) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1447) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onInputFormatChanged(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:920) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.readSourceOmittingSampleData(MediaCodecRenderer.java:948) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:763) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1015) 
                                                                                                  at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:510) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I was using exoplayer for a video url to be playing, it is like instagram reels, so i am coming up with this error , that leads to not to began the play of video after some videos get plyaed, like after 5-6 videos, i was encoutering this issue , that leads to freeze of device , i had to kill the app to let it work again.

Comment: Have you put your ExoPlayer into RecyclerView items? Please provide more info about how you implemented your code. @prabhat biswal

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to call setEnableDecoderFallback(true) while creating the ExoPlayer object, it will try to find the available media codec from all the available codec lists. If you don't call setEnableDecoderFallback(true), the enableDecoderFallback is false, it will only use the first available codec and fails to init in some devices.

val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this)
.setRenderersFactory(DefaultRenderersFactory(this).setEnableDecoderFallback(true)).build()

Reference - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8987#issuecomment-1311420021

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution worked for me. However, it should be noted that there may be a slight hit to performance optimisation using a less efficient or slower decoder.